# just trying to make a histogram in R

Tags: r, histogram

```
wayne <- c(46, 49, 64, 70, 72, 73, 73, 77, 78, 79, 79, 79, 81, 81, 81, 81,
           81, 82, 82, 84)
hist(wayne, 7)
hist(wayne, breaks=7)
```

thats all I've got. Trying to make a histogram with 7 breaks but keep getting the error:

```
hist.default(wayne, breaks = 7) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Comment: Your code works for me without any errors. What is the error message you get?

Comment: Error in hist.default(wayne, breaks = 7) : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: Restart R or run `rm(hist,c)` and try your code again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
wayne <- c(46, 49, 64, 70, 72, 73, 73, 77, 78, 79, 79, 79, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 82, 82, 84)
breaks <- 7 # By doing this you can check if R is reading the value as numeric as shown in the next line
is.numeric(breaks) # R should output "TRUE" and you can now plot your histogram although you should note that R decides the best number of breaks and you can only suggest a number - it may not take that number! 
hist(wayne, breaks)
```

This creates 8 breaks.
To make sure you get 7 breaks for your histogram you could do the following:

```
wayne <- c(46, 49, 64, 70, 72, 73, 73, 77, 78, 79, 79, 79, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 82, 82, 84)
breaks <- c(46, 52.3, 58.6, 64.9, 70.6, 76.9, 83.2, 89.5)
hist(wayne,breaks)
```

This has created a histogram with 7 breaks

Comment: Would you please stop unformating the edits I'm trying to do for your answer? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Sorry I was trying to update my answer, I'm new to this - no more editing from me - sorry again!

Comment: You can edit your post as many times as you want, just keep the formating

Comment: Ok, I am done with the answer now anyway. Thanks for making it look better!